# Visual Basic like GUI for Python with arrays of text boxes and labels

Tags: python, user-interface, open-source

There are lots of GUI environments for Python like Qt, tKinter, wx, PySimpleGUI, etc. so I have not been able to go through very many of them. I would like to know if there is one which is

1. somewhat similar to Visual Basic's (drag and drop and resize),
2. allows for arrays of textboxes and labels.
3. It should preferably be open source,
4. should create stand alone *.exe files,
5. and not requiring browsers.

Answer (score 2):

The closest match to your requirements is probably [PySimpleGUI](http://www.PySimpleGUI.org).  Doesn't have drag and drop, but you don't really need it.  It takes 1 line of code to configure and place a widget into your window.  You easily make an "array of textboxes and labels".  Runs on tkinter or Qt.

Answer (score 1):

Would that there were a simple drag and drop GUi builder for Python!

You might try [appJar](http://appjar.info).  It's not drag and drop but it seems pretty straightforward.

QtDesigner is drag and drop. It's part of the [PyQT](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt) suite.  QtDesigner creates XML (.ui) files which can then be translated to .py files.  [Michael Herrmann's site](https://build-system.fman.io/qt-designer-download)
shows how to do this with a minimum amount of overhead.

Answer (score 1):

I personally recommend my project https://github.com/cdhigh/tkinter-designer.

**tkinter-designer** implemented a add-on in VB6, you can design your GUI in VB6 (drag and drop, resize, **align**, color, key-bind,...), and then this add-on generate a complete code frame. what you will do is add logic code in event method like coding in VB.

PS: You can install nano version of vb6.